# Sending jQuery.serialize form via POST, expecting JSON response from controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, cakephp-2.0

I would like to ask you how could I send ajax request with serialized by jQuery form and recieve JSON response from controller? I have been trying many solutions but none of them worked for me. I have a little experience in that matter.

Can you provide any good example? Thank You!

1. Send post with serialized form (POST) by AJAX
2. Process action in controller function and obtain JSON response in ajax -> success

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.1

---

My ajax request

```
       $.ajax({
       type: "post",
       url: location.pathname + "/edit",
       data: data,
       success: function(response) {
            $("#content").html(response); // i would like to recieve JSON response
            alert(response);              // here ;C

       },
       error: function(){        
                alert("error");
       }
       });
```

---

Part of my function in controller

```
      public function admin_edit(){
        //................ some logic passed 
        if($this->request->is('ajax')){
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->disableCache();
        foreach($this->request->data['User'] as $key => $value){
            if(empty($value)){
                unset($this->request->data['User'][$key]);
            }
        }
        $this->User->id = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Użytkownik został zmodyfikowany');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash('Nie zmodyfikowano użytkownika');
        }
      }
```

---

What i would like to recieve is JSON response from the controller.
example

```
  [{"id":"1", "username":"test", ... }]
```

Comment: have you tried using [serialize](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key) (eg `$this->set('_serialize', array('posts'));`) ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't have worked :(

Comment: what error did it give?

Comment: both `.html(response)` and `alert(response)` will only give you `[object Object]` or `[object Object,object Object]` if the server-side code is working correctly.

Comment: @Kevin B returns HTML code, not [object][object]
Nunser i'll check it right away

Comment: No, it returns json according to your question. *"i would like to recieve JSON response"* and *"What i would like to recieve is JSON response from the controller. example"* and `[{"id":"1", "username":"test", ... }]`

Comment: I can assure You it isn't :) [screenshot](http://i41.tinypic.com/bg4i8n.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think what confuse you are little stuff, but mixed together can be a bit hard to debug for someone with little experience. I'll post a basic example of what should work for you, and you iterate over that. Tell us if there's another error (it's easier to check for specific errors rather than the view/controller possible error).

First, in the ajax call, change for `console.log(response);` to debug better

```
    //alert(response);
    console.log(response);
},
error: function(){        
    alert("error");
    console.log(response);
}
});
```

And in the controller

```
  public function admin_edit(){
    //................ some logic passed 
    if($this->request->is('ajax')){
        /* layout not necessary if you have autoRender = false */
        //$this->layout = 'ajax';
        /* actually, no need for this either with _serialize, but add it if you have unwanted html rendering problems */
        //$this->autoRender = false;

        $this->set(compact('user'));

        /* other code that doesn't really matter for the example ... */

        $this->User->id = $this->request->data['User']['id'];
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
           /* NO!! */
           //$this->Session->setFlash('Użytkownik został zmodyfikowany');
           //return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

           $status = 'OK';
           $message = 'Użytkownik został zmodyfikowany';
           $this->set(compact('message', 'status'));
        }
        /* NO EITHER!! */
        //$this->Session->setFlash('Nie zmodyfikowano użytkownika');
           $status = 'NOT-OK';
           $message = 'Not sure what your flash says but let\'s assume it an error alert';
           $this->set(compact('message', 'status'));

        //serialize variables you have set for the "ghost" view
        $this->set('_serialize', array('user', 'message', 'status'));
    }
  }
```

I think your major flaw here is to return a redirect. That's a no no for json. What you are doing with that is giving the ajax call the html for the index action. That makes no sense. If you want the action to return JSON, then all cases must return json, no html whatsoever. So, no `setFlash`, no `redirect`. What I normally do here is to return the JSON data with a status and a message (like in the code above). Then, in the ajax call, on success, you parse the JSON data, read the status, if ok you redirect (via js), and if not, show the error message you got.

Hope it clear things for you.

[tiny edit]: `json_encode` will also work, but when in CakePHP, do what CakePHP(ians?) do ([serialize](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)) (because you don't need to echo the variables).

Comment: I did as in your example, but i have empty response in console.log :(

Comment: forgot to include the status and the message there... let me correct that... There. Still getting empty response? (I just changed the last line)

Comment: Yes, still empty response. However if I use echo json_encode then it's ok, but i would like to use Cake way

Comment: make sure you have commented `autoRender = false` and `layout = ajax`. And also, cake behaves a little weird with characters that are not standart, so for debugging purposes, change the message to something simple with "vanilla" letters.

Comment: Did as You suggested and still empty

Comment: I was missing in ajax request field dataType: "Json", now it works perfectly, thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There's an example at [JQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

*Example: Post to the test.php page and get content which has been returned in json format*

```
 <?php echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm")); ?>
```

.

```
$.post( location.pathname + "/edit", data, function( data ) {
  console.log( data.name ); // John
  console.log( data.time ); // 2pm
}, "json");
```

So plugging in your ajax call is something like:

```
$.post( "test.php", data, function(response) {
            $("#content").html(response); 
            alert(response);              

       }, "json");
```

Edit:  If you're not getting the correct response, please show the php code that echos or returns the json..it's not anywhere in that function you provided.